# On and off bluetooth connection in Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, windows-10

I am trying to create an application that has a functionality to search for and turn-on (if available) the bluetooth device. How can I find a bluetooth device is available or not? If available I want to check is that enabled. If disabled I need to enable it.

I want to do this from my C# application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it but there is a library exposing Personal Area Networks to C#. Take a look at:

https://32feet.codeplex.com/

It may contain what you are looking for.